# How to get the better visibility into the power automate flows?

Tags: sharepoint, powerbi, powerapps, power-automate, power-platform

I'm trying to find a way to access flow run logs via API or some other automated way of exporting them. I need to export the run logs to SharePoint or any other data source. How to achieve this?

Can anyone help me have clear steps to achieve this?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/admin/analytics-flow?source=recommendations

Something like that?

Comment: Take a reference to this article: https://2die4it.com/2020/07/08/custom-connector-to-get-flow-run-history/.